# How 3rd party app obtains my custom defined service permission to start my service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-service, android-permissions

Here is my manifest file with my background service declaration

```
......
    <service android:name="com.example.MyService" 
               android:process=":service" 
               android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.START_MY_SERVICE" />
         </intent-filter>
......
```

1. What should a 3rd party app declare in its manifest which is
   interested in binding with my service ?
2. Also how does the verification of the permission( or custom defined permission) happens in my app when the 3rd party app tries to bind to my service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is my manifest file with my background service declaration

First, do not use separate processes without a *very* good reason.

Second, do not re-use Android standard permissions for your own purposes, unless those purposes are *really* closely tied to what Android secures with that permission. You should only be requiring `BIND_VPN_SERVICE` if your app will be doing VPN-related stuff, such as binding the VPN on the caller's behalf.

> What should a 3rd party app declare in its manifest which is interested in binding with my service should declare in its manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE" />
```

> Also how does the verification of the permission happens in my app when the 3rd party app tries to bind to my service ?

That is handled automatically for you by Android when somebody calls `startService()` or `bindService()` with an `Intent` that identifies your service. If the caller does not hold the permission listed in `android:permission`, they will get a `SecurityException`.

Comment: How to get the 3rd party app's UID to verify his identity within my service's onBind() before I even return him the IBinder?

Comment: @AKh: You can call `getCallingUid()` from your `Binder`. However, please bear in mind that the Android permissions system is not a licensing system.